# Storing PDF files in Firebase and Download into the App

Tags: android, firebase

I am New to Android Dev.
In my App, i want to allow users the will to **Download Pdf Files** because i figured out that putting the PDF files in the assets folder will increase apk size, which I don't want. But files must be stored inside the App when downloaded not in the SD Card or the internal memory.

**Is it possible to Store Pdf files in Firebase and then when user clicks Download button, the file is downloaded into the application?** and How.

Comment: what does "inside the app" and "into the application" mean?

Comment: Tim Castelijns i do not want the users to save the Files in their drives. But the files should only be accesible when user is in the App. Just like How you save Facebook Videos. You cant access them from your local drive unless in the App.

Answer (score 0):

Save the documents to Firebase Storage and set metadata for the file type.